# npm run watch doesn't run: no such file or directory, open '/Users/usr/package.json'

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I believe this might be happening because I used brew to install npm; I think I might have two different versions. Here is the error:

```
npm run watch
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.1_1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
npm ERR! path /Users/Nicolas/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nicolas/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nicolas/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Nicolas/Code/wordpress/wp-content/themes/IMFA-theme/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried the following:

- brew doctor (gives a lot of warnings and doesn't seem to change anything)
- brew unlink and re-link (doesn't seem to do anything)

For what it's worth, I uninstalled and re-installed brew recently, and I know there are some unlinked kegs; I see this when I run brew doctor, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Other npm commands still seem to work, like npm install. However, npm run watch, in a directory where I want to compile SCSS, is giving me the error above. Any help is appreciated

Comment: in your package.json file what is the value of "scripts" : { "watch" : "?" }

Comment: Looks to me like you are running npm in the wrong folder, you are running it in your home folder which is usually not where the root of a project would be. At least npm doesnt find a package.json file there. Make sure you are in the right directory and try again.

Comment: if I have cd'd into the project folder and use npm run watch, I still get the above error. I seem to get it regardless of where I try to execute npm

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem npm err no such file or directory, open '/Users/usr/package.json' and I got the solution.
to solve the problem,you need to init your environment,like $ xxx init ,then use npm install to install the  dependences.